# Handling exceptions in a Spring-Integration transformer

Tags: spring-integration

I have a [spring-integration](/questions/tagged/spring-integration) transformer that accepts a org.w3c.dom.Document and returns a domain object. And this is nice. If there are elements missing I raise an application exception.

However, I'd like to get that exception onto the error channel but instead the way it currently works by bubbling back through a chain of handlers. It would be nice if there a way of specifying an error channel in the case of a failed transform.

I could:

- pass the message through a router to check for missing elements before (or after) the transformer
- route the message

However that means both parsing the document twice and a bit of a re-write.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer I came up with was to change the return type of the transformer from the domain POJO to a Message. And then, in the exception case, to return a Message. The exception is then routed to the correct handler by a Payload Type Router.

Answer (score 0):

In order to determine where exception messages should go, you need to set the "errorChannel" header. For example,

```
<int:chain input-channel="myInputChannel">
    <int:header-enricher>
        <int:error-channel ref="myErrorChannel" />
    </int:header-enricher>
    <int:transformer ref="myTransformer" />
    <!-- Further actions after the transformer here -->
</int:chain>
```

This chain will assign the error channel header before calling the transformer. If the transformer succeeds, it continues down the chain, but if it throws an exception a `MessagingException` will be sent as a message to myErrorChannel. (If you want the way to handle an exception to be different later on in the chain, you could have another header-enricher after the transformer to update the errorChannel header to the next place you want to send exceptions.)

Refer to the details in the [Error Handling](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/configuration.html#namespace-errorhandler) section of the Spring Integration documentation.