# How to change Failed Message of Messaging Exception in Spring

Tags: java, spring, error-handling, spring-integration

I am using spring integration based Component. That components receives some XML and enriched that XML with some more content.

However, if an exception occurs , then i want to sent the received input XML as the failed message, however in current scenario, it will hold the partially enriched XML as there failed Message.

Is there any way through which I can change the failed message of the Exception , which in turn is wrapped by the Messaging Exception.

Comment: maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6490904/handling-exceptions-in-a-spring-integration-transformer

Answer (score 1):

As it is so specific case, we need to see your configuration and especially where is an `error-channel` and how you enrich XML.

However, keep in mind, that `Message` is immutable object and each interaction with it provides a new Message. But the `payload` is out of scope of the messsaging and it might not be immutable. And if change of some property of your payload and then you get some exception, you end up in the `ErrorMessage` with `inbound` message (failed), but payload might change its state.

Looks like it is your case.

You should think about some `payload-cloning` variant before you start to enrich it.
Here are some advices on the matter: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/INT-2979

Comment: If you start with some immutable object (such as a string), you can simply make a reference to it in a header (header-enricher with `<header name="orig" expression="payload"/>`). Then, it will be available as a header (orig) on the failedMessage. If it's a mutable object then the changes will be in both places, so then you'll need to clone, as Artem suggests.